# Script to display board game matches based on criteria

Tags: google-apps-script

My apologies if my wording is confusing, as I am new to scripting and programming. I have a board game list with my friends that have the list of games we own, the estimated time it takes to play the game, and the min/max players required to play the game. A wonderful member of the community created a script where I can input the amount of players I have, and the amount of time we have on our hands, and the script would list the available games we could lay base off of my input. Currently, I input the players and times on line two of the script ( var gamesThatFitCriteria = findGames(4,50);  ). I would like the script to take the values ofdesignated two cells on the sheet to create these numbers.

Here is the sheet (editable for all, I have a separate private copy) with details on what I would like to accomplish, as well as my current script.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AFTr_ji5iz8BJU9_OkZ1Xhfb9hg9ARAaRXfdVx2Y8pU/edit?usp=sharing

```
function runThis() {
  var gamesThatFitCriteria = findGames(4,50);
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(gamesThatFitCriteria.join('<br />'));
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, "Games")
}

function findGames(player, timeInMinutes) {
  var games=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=games.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange(3,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn());
  var values=rg.getValues();
  var result = [];
  values.forEach(function(r){var name=r[0];var time=r[2];var minPlayer=r[3];var maxPlayer=r[4];if(time<=timeInMinutes && player >= minPlayer && player <= maxPlayer) {result.push(name);}});
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You want to retrieve the values from the cells `B2:B3` on the sheet of `Look Here`.
- You want to use the retrieved values to `valueOfB2` and `valueOfB3` of `var gamesThatFitCriteria = findGames(valueOfB2, valueOfB3);`.
- You want to achieve this by modifying your script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify the function of `runThis()` as follows.

```
function runThis() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Look Here");
  var [[valueOfB2], [valueOfB3]] = sheet.getRange("B2:B3").getValues();
  var gamesThatFitCriteria = findGames(valueOfB2, valueOfB3);
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(gamesThatFitCriteria.join('<br />'));
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, "Games")
}
```

#### Note:

- In your shared Spreadsheet, there are 2 functions of `findGames` in the files of `Get Games Dialogue` and `On Open`. In this case, one of 2 functions of `findGames` is run. So please be careful this.
- In your script, when you run the function of `runThis` on the sheet of `Games`, the retrieved values are displayed. When you run the function on the sheet of `Look Here`, no values are displayed. Please be careful this.

  - If you want to display the values on the sheet of `Look Here`, please modify `var sh=games.getActiveSheet();` to `var sh=games.getSheetByName("Games");`.

#### Reference:

- [getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.